# Landau Notation/Big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

In our class the following exercise/example was given:

Compute n_0 and c from the formal definition of each Landau symbol to show that :

2^100n belongs O(n^2).

Then in the Solution the following was done:

n_0=2^100 and c=1.

Show for each n>n_0: 2^100*n=<n^2.

It is true that: n_0^2=2^100*n_0 and for all n>2^100: n^2-2^100n>n^2 -n*n=n^2 - n^2=0.

I have some questions:

1. We are looking for n_0 and c, but somehow we give values to them? And why those values in particular? Why can't n_0=2? and c=34? Is there a logic behind all of this?
2. In the last part, I don't see how that expression proves anything, it looks redundant

Answer (score 0):

If you read the definition of big-O notation, it is precisely so that if you can **find** one such *n<sub>0</sub>* and *c* that the inequality holds for all numbers greater than *n<sub>0</sub>*, then the big-O relation holds.

Of course you can choose another *n<sub>0</sub>*, for example a bigger one. As long as you find one, you have proven the relation.

Although for better help with such questions, I recommend [Math.stachexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [CS.stakhexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).